# What are the most reliable analyses of Stirner's intellectual context?

Tags: ethics, society, anarchism

Difficult to underestimate the influence of e.g. Nietzsche, but has anyone done the same with Stirner?

Comment: "Difficult to underestimate" Do you mean his influence is slightly below zero?

Comment: You can start from [Max Stirner](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/max-stirner/) : "At the time of his death, Stirner's brief period of notoriety was long over, his book had been out of print for several years, and there was little sign that his work might have any longer term impact. Since then, however, The Ego and Its Own has been translated into at least eight languages, and appeared in over one hundred editions."

Comment: @user. You have an answer to your Stirner question.

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix your typos.

Comment: Are you asking whether someone has had difficulty in underestimating Stirner?

Comment: 'Complementary' doesn't look quite right in context. I doubt if you mean 'complimentary'. 'What are the most reliable analyses of Stirner's intellectual context?' Is this what you mean ? Alter my amendment if it is not right.

Answer (score 2):

User - welcome to PSE.

Stirner has not been totally neglected. Five texts come to mind :

Max Stirner, The Ego and His Own: The Case of the Individual Against Authority. Translated by Steven Byington. Mineóla, NY: Dover Publications, Inc., 2005.

Jeffrey H. Barker,  Individualism and Community: The State in Marx and Early Anarchism. New York : Greenwood Press, 1986. [Particular attention paid to Stirner.]

Diederik Dettmeijer,  Max Stirner, Published by Paris L Age d Homme 1979 (1979). [French text]

J. Carroll, Max Stirner: The Ego and His Own (London, 1971).

R. W.K. Paterson, The Nihilistic Egoist (Oxford, 1971).

Also Marx counts because his critique of 'Saint Max' in The German Ideology is an attack on Stirner. Stirner survives through Marx whose work is still widely read, of course.